# Getting Value of Child Element

Tags: javascript, html, console.log, getelementsbytagname, getelementsbyclassname

I am writing code that can be applied to a webpage. I want to get the value of "A" as a variable. I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("inProgressGrade");
```

And

```
document.getElementsByClassName("b");
```

Here is the code I'm extracting from, to make it more complex all the values I want to get have the same class as each other.

```
<td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
90.62% 
<b>A</b>
</td>
```

Another one on the same webpage:

```
<td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
87.10% 
<b>B</b>
</td>
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("b"));
```

```html
<td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB;              padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">87.10% <b>B</b></td>
```

```js
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("inProgressGrade"));
```

```html
<td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB;              padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">87.10% <b>B</b></td>
```

Comment: So you want to extract the percentage value before the letter?

Comment: I just want to extract the letters

Comment: On your first example, you are trying to select the `td` by id, while you only gave it a class. In the second, you are looking for the class name `b`, but the `td`'s class name is `inProgressGrade `.

Comment: Fixed it still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.querySelector()` with `textContent` just like :

```
document.querySelector('.inProgressGrade b').textContent
```

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.inProgressGrade>b').textContent);
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
      90.62%
      <b>A</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

If you want the both letters you could use `.querySelectorAll()` with loop like :

```
var letters = document.querySelectorAll('.inProgressGrade b');

for( var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
    console.log( letters[i].textContent );
}
```

Code:

```js
var letters = document.querySelectorAll('.inProgressGrade b');

for (var i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
  console.log(letters[i].textContent);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
      90.62%
      <b>A</b>
    </td>
    <td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
      87.10%
      <b>B</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How would I assign a variable to each value?

Comment: Describe more please what you want to achieve with a small example if possible.

Comment: I might of figured it out, I will report back

Comment: Here is what I tried, not quite sure why it is not working though https://jsfiddle.net/ap98wz66/5/ I added an external resource that puts the command line in the output box

Comment: That happen since array is zero-based in javascript, check the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ap98wz66/6/

Comment: Worked thank you, I will post what I'm planning for the rest of the code one I finish it if your interested.

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll` will be your friend here. You will need to identify all `b` elements that are underneath `.inProgressGrade`. You will also have to use a loop to iterate through all your elements, since there are multiples.

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".inProgressGrade b");
var vals = [];
for(var i in els) {
  if (els[i] && els[i].innerText)
    vals.push(els[i].innerText);
}
for(var i in vals) {
  console.log(vals[i]);
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>

<tr>
<td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" 
class="inProgressGrade">
90.62% 
<b>A</b>
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" 
class="inProgressGrade">
87.10% 
<b>B</b>
</td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementsByClassName()` return an array, therefore you have to loop through it. After that all you need to do is use `.innerText` to get its "value".

```js
(function() {
  const allTds = document.getElementsByClassName('inProgressGrade'); //get all td-elements for which you want the value

  var values = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < allTds.length; ++i) {
    const bEl = allTds[i].getElementsByTagName('b')[0]; // takes the first b-element, you'll need another loop if there are multiple

    /* Since <b> is an inline element it will be part of its parents innerText */
    const textWithChild = allTds[i].innerText;
    const text = textWithChild.substring(0, textWithChild.length - bEl.innerText.length - 1);
    console.log(`The value of ${bEl.innerText} is <${text}>`);
  }
})()
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
      90.62%
      <b>A</b>
    </td>
    <td style="width:60px; border: 1px solid #ABABAB; padding: 2px;" class="inProgressGrade">
      87.10%
      <b>B</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```